# UIButton background image change from another button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is it possible that I can change the background image of some button when I click on another button?

I basically have 10 buttons, and I want the user to know which button is currently clicked. So what happens is each button has 2 images. One for selected and one for not selected.

I want to create a function which will reset the background images of all the buttons. And in the method for each button, I will add this reset function and then change the background image of that specific button.

Can someone suggest how is that possible?

I know how to change the background image of a button when that button is clicked.

This how my buttons look:

```
- (IBAction)posterButton:(id)sender {}
- (IBAction)colorInvertButton:(id)sender {}
```

etc..

Comment: The code that handles your "reset" button just needs to reference the other buttons. It's not really any different than what you do in the handler for each button.

Comment: I have added only the Action function for those buttons in the .m file. Do I need to create a property for them in .h file too?

Comment: You'll need a reference to all of the buttons so yes, you need properties for all of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the documentation for UIButton: configure each button like this:

```
[button setControlImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setControlImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

^^this can also be done in interface builder btw.

There are also the states `UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateHighlighted` and `UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted`, but this is optional.

A button also has a selected state, inherited from `UIControl`.

If you want to have only one selected button at a time, try this (_selectedButton should be declared as an instance variable):

```
- (UIButton *)selectedButton {
    return _selectedButton;
}
- (void)setSelectedButton:(UIButton *)b {
    if(b != _selectedButton) {
        _selectedButton.selected = NO;
        b.selected = YES;
        _selectedButton = b;
    }
}
```